# Android Studio 2.1.2 dimens.xml file correpted with every newly created project

Tags: android-studio

In my android studio 2.1.2 every time when creating new application it's corrupt **dimens.xml** and **colors.xml** files.Then get error on layout file.

**Dimens.xml** file like bellow.

[image]

**Then I checked dimens content and it's like:**

�PNG   IHDR   @   @    `�U  IDATx��C�Q@�;�m۶m'��6�qֱm۶m۶�g
!a}$��aGb�Xt�a~�A ��G5B�TG�D���A\�IN���I�{Ĥ��sf�#f���p1���

Then getting errors on each and every properties that used values stored in dimens.xml

**Example errors getting with bellow values:**

```
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
```

I can't create application with this issue.Still I am didn't tried with reinstalling and looking solution without doing reinstall.

Comment: try File > Invalidate Caches/Restart . and than try to create project

Comment: @KDeogharkar Didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

1. Close android studio.
2. Simply move your project folder to another path.
3. Open android studio & open that project from the new path.